# Idiom for obeying propagate_on_copy_assignment in Container without allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, allocator

Suppose you have a Container which internally uses other standard containers to form more complex data structures.  Thankfully, the standard containers are already designed to do all the necessary work to ensure allocators are copied/assigned etc.

So, normally if we have some Container `c`, and internally it has an `std::vector<int>`, we can write a copy-assignment operator that just says:

```
Container& operator = (const Container& c) { m_vec = c.m_vec; return *this; }
```

In fact we don't even have to write that (since it's just what the default copy assignment operator does), but let's just say that in this case there's some extra required logic that the default operator wouldn't do:

```
Container& operator = (const Container& c) 
{
   /* some other stuff... */
   m_vec = c.m_vec;
   return *this; 
}
```

So, in this case there's no problem because the vector assignment operator does all the work for us to make sure that allocators are properly copied-on-assignment or not copied.

But... what if we have a vector which we can't simply copy-assign.  Suppose it is a vector of pointers to some other internal structure.

Say we have an internal vector which holds pointers: `std::vector<node*, Alloc>`

So, normally in our copy-assignment operator, we'd have to say:

```
Container& operator = (const Container& other) 
{
   vector<node*, Alloc>::allocator_type alloc = m_vec.get_allocator();
   for (auto it = m_vec.begin(); it != m_vec.end(); ++it) alloc.deallocate(*it);
   m_vec.clear();

   for (auto it = other.m_vec.begin(); it != other.m_vec.end(); ++it)
   {
     node* n = alloc.allocate(1); // this is wrong, we might need to use other.get_allocator() here!
     alloc.construct(n, *(*it));
     m_vec.push_back(n);
   }

   return *this; 
}
```

So in the above example, we need to manually deallocate all the `node` objects in `m_vec`, and then construct new node objects from the RHS container.  (Note that I'm using the same allocator object the vector uses internally in order to allocate node objects.)

But if we want to be standards compliant here and AllocatorAware, we need to check if `allocator_traits<std::vector<node*, Alloc>::allocator_type>` sets `propagate_on_container_copy_assign` to true.  If it does, we need to use the other container's allocator to construct the copied nodes.

But... our container type `Container` doesn't use it's own allocator.  It just uses an internal `std::vector`... so how can we tell our internal `std::vector` instance to use a copied allocator if necessary?  The vector doesn't have something like a "use_allocator" or "set_allocator" member function.

So, the only thing I came up with is something like:

```
if (std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value)
{
   m_vec = std::vector<node*, Alloc>(other.get_allocator());
}
```

...and then we could construct our nodes with the return value of `m_vec.get_allocator();`

Is this a valid idiom for creating an allocator aware container that doesn't keep it's own allocator, but rather defers to an internal standard container?

Comment: The call to ``deallocate`` is missing the size argument (presumably 1), but the allocator has the wrong ``value_type`` (``node*`` instead of ``node``) and ``rebind`` is necessary (as shown by Howard Hinnant). Fortunately, this code does not compile, but it goes to show that bad calls and UB are not far away when dealing with allocators directly.

Answer (score 6):

One problem with using `swap` to implement copy assignment in this example is that if `propagate_on_assignment == true_type` and `propagate_on_container_swap == false_type`, then the allocator is not propagated from `other` to `*this`, because the `swap` refuses to do so.

A second problem with this approach is that if both `propagate_on_assignment` and `propagate_on_container_swap == true_type` but `other.m_vec.get_allocator() != m_vec.get_allocator()`, then you do propagate the allocator but you get undefined behavior at the point of `swap`.

To do this right, you really need to design your `operator=` from first principals.  For this exercise I'm assuming that `Container` looks something like this:

```
template <class T, class Alloc>
struct Container
{
    using value_type = T;
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Alloc::value_type, value_type>{}, "");
    using allocator_type = Alloc;

    struct node {};
    using NodePtr = typename std::pointer_traits<
              typename std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::pointer>::template
                                                                   rebind<node>;
    using NodePtrAlloc = typename std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::template
                                                          rebind_alloc<NodePtr>;
    std::vector<NodePtr, NodePtrAlloc> m_vec;
    // ...
```

I.e. `Container` is templated on `T` and `Alloc`, and that the implementation allows for the possibility that `Alloc` is using "fancy pointers" (i.e. `node*` is actually a class type).

In this event, here is what the `Container` copy assignment operator might look like:

```
Container&
operator = (const Container& other) 
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        using NodeAlloc = typename std::allocator_traits<NodePtrAlloc>::template
                                                                 rebind_alloc<node>;
        using NodeTraits = std::allocator_traits<NodeAlloc>;

        NodeAlloc alloc = m_vec.get_allocator();
        for (auto node_ptr : m_vec)
        {
            NodeTraits::destroy(alloc, std::addressof(*node_ptr));
            NodeTraits::deallocate(alloc, node_ptr, 1);
        }
        if (typename NodeTraits::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment{})
            m_vec = other.m_vec;
        m_vec.clear();
        m_vec.reserve(other.m_vec.size());
        NodeAlloc alloc2 = m_vec.get_allocator();
        for (auto node_ptr : other.m_vec)
        {
            using deleter = allocator_deleter<NodeAlloc>;
            deleter hold{alloc2, 1};
            std::unique_ptr<node, deleter&> n{NodeTraits::allocate(alloc2, 1),
                                              hold};
            NodeTraits::construct(alloc2, std::addressof(*n), *node_ptr);
            hold.constructed = true;
            m_vec.push_back(n.get());
            n.release();
        }
    }
    return *this; 
}
```

Explanation:

In order to allocate and deallocate memory with a compatible allocator, we need to use `std::allocator_traits` to create an "`allocator<node>`".  This is named `NodeAlloc` in the above example.  It is also convenient to form traits for this allocator, termed `NodeTraits` above.

The first job is to a **converted** copy of the lhs allocator (converted from `allocator<node*>` to `allocator<node>`), and use that allocator to *both* destroy and deallocate the lhs nodes.  `std::addressof` is needed to convert the possibly "fancy pointer" to an actual `node*` in the call to `destroy`.

Next, and this is a bit subtle, we need to propagate `m_vec.get_allocator()` to `m_vec`, but only if `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` is true.  The copy assignment operator of the `vector` is the best way to do this.  This unnecessarily copy some `NodePtr`s, however I still believe this is the best way to get that allocator propagated.  We could also do the vector assignment if `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` is false, thus avoiding the if-statement.  The assignment would not propagate the allocator if `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` is false, but then we still might assign some `NodePtr`s, when all we really need is a no-op.

If `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` is true, and the two allocators are unequal, the `vector` copy assignment operator will correctly handle dumping the lhs resources for us prior to assigning the allocators.  This is a complication that is easy to overlook, and thus best left up to the `vector` copy assignment operator.

If `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` is false, that means we don't need to worry about the case where we have unequal allocators.  We aren't going to swap any resources.

In any event, after doing this, we should `clear()` the lhs.  This operation does not dump `capacity()` and so is not wasteful.  At this point we have a zero-sized lhs with the correct allocator, and perhaps even some non-zero `capacity()` to play with.

As an optimization we can `reserve` with `other.size()`, in case the lhs capacity is not sufficient.  This line is not necessary for correctness.  It is a pure optimization.

Just in case `m_vec.get_allocator()` might now return a new allocator, we go ahead and get a fresh copy of it, named `alloc2` above.

We can now use `alloc2` to allocate, construct, and store new nodes which are copy constructed from the rhs.

To be exception safe, we should use an RAII device to hold the allocated pointer while we construct into it, and push_back it into the vector. Either the construction can throw, as can the `push_back()`.  The RAII device must be aware of whether it needs to just deallocate, or both destruct and deallocate in an exception circumstance.  The RAII device also needs to be "fancy pointer"-aware.  It turns out that it is very easy to build all of this using `std::unique_ptr` combined with a custom deleter:

```
template <class Alloc>
class allocator_deleter
{
    using traits = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>;
public:
    using pointer   = typename traits::pointer;
    using size_type = typename traits::size_type;
private:
    Alloc& alloc_;
    size_type s_;
public:
    bool constructed = false;

    allocator_deleter(Alloc& a, size_type s) noexcept
        : alloc_(a)
        , s_(s)
    {}

    void
    operator()(pointer p) noexcept
    {
        if (constructed)
            traits::destroy(alloc_, std::addressof(*p));
        traits::deallocate(alloc_, p, s_);
    }
};
```

Note the consistent use of `std::allocator_traits` for all accesses to the allocator.  This allows `std::allocator_traits` to provide defaults so that the author of `Alloc` need not provide them.  For example `std::allocator_traits` can provide default implementations for `construct`, `destroy`, and `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment`.

Also note the consistent avoidance of the assumption that `NodePtr` is a `node*`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to leverage existing functionality. Personally, I would go a step further and actually leverage an existing implementation to do the copy. Generally, it seems a suitable copy-and-swap idiom is the easiest approach to implement copy assign:

```
Container& Container::operator= (Container const& other) {
    Container(other,
              std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::propagate_on_assignment
              ? other.get_allocator()
              : this->get_allocator()).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

This approach makes a few assumptions, though:

1. The copy constructor is implemented in a form which [optionally] gets an allocator passed:

   ```
   Container::Container(Container const& other, Alloc allcoator = Alloc()));
   ```
2. It assumes that the `swap()` appropriately swaps the allocator.

It is worth pointing out that this approach has the advantage of being reasonably simple and providing a strong exception guarantee but it uses newly allocated memory. If the memory of the LHS object is reused it may result in better performance, e.g., because the used memory is already resonably close to the processor. That is, for an initial implementation I would use the copy and swap implementation (using an extended copy constructor as mentioned above) and replace it by a more involved implementation if profiling indicates that's needed.

Comment: In my scenario, `Container` doesn't have a `get_allocator()` but rather it simply defers to an internal `std::vector`.

Comment: @siler so write `get_allocator`.  It can get it from its internal container.  It needs get it to allocate said pointers-to-data stored in the internal `vector` anyhow.